# Hide part of object during animation

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

I am animating the opening of a shutter door. I don't want to deform this door like in real life, just move it on the Z axis.

How would I mask or hide the part that will obviously stick through the roof?

[image: door]

Comment: boolean modifier with a not rendered object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use some transparent object and make the boolean difference with the door.

Modifier setup on right below:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, if for instance the boolean fails, you can modify the door material so that everything above an empty is set transparent:

[image]

The node setting compares the empty position (object texture coordinates, so one location) to the correspondant location on the object surface (also one location). If the Z part of these locations are showing that the door is upper the empty, alpha is set to zero.

[image]

Comment: Really like the second idea, has scope for so many other uses. Thanks